# Conditions on integral cubic polynomial with cyclic group #2

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, galois-theory

Numerical analysis shows that:

> If the cubic irreducible polynomial $T^3 -pT+s$ with integral coefficients with $p\neq 3$ prime has cubic Galois group, then $s\equiv 0\mod p$.

After exhausting calculations, one finds that the generator of the Galois group is:
$$g(\alpha)=\frac{3p}{r}\alpha^{2}-\frac{1}{2}(1+\frac{9s}{r})\alpha-\frac{2p^{2}}{r},\quad r=\sqrt{4p^3-27s^2}$$
so that $$g^3(\alpha)\equiv 0\mod p \quad \Rightarrow \quad s\equiv 0\mod p$$

I would like to learn a more elegant, algebraic number theory way to find this result. (Note this question is different from 
[this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2272385/conditions-on-integral-cubic-polynomial-with-cyclic-group-and-prime-coefficients) where I learned a method that I didn't succeed to apply in this case).

Thanks.

Comment: You'll need $p\neq3$, since $T^3-3T+1$ has cyclic galois group.