# conditions on integral cyclic cubic polynomial

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, polynomials, galois-theory

> If the irreducible cubic polynomial $T^3 -pT+s$ with integral coefficients with $p\neq 3$ prime has cubic Galois group, then $s\equiv 0\mod p$.

Comment: You should give links to [the earlier developments](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2272385/11619)

Answer (score 0):

just so you know, $x^2 + 27 y^2 = 4 p^3$ is impossible for primes $p \equiv 2 \pmod 3.$ For primes $p \equiv 1 \pmod 3,$ there are two answers to $x^2 + 27 y^2 = 4 p^3$ with $x,y$ positive integers. One has $y$ divisible by $p.$ The other shows how your $T^3 - pT + s,$ with $s=y,$ becomes reducible; for example, $t^3 - 7 t + 6$ has positive integers roots $t=1,t=2$ and negative $-(1+2) = -3.$

Construction of these comes from this dichotomy: for $p \equiv 1 \pmod 3,$ we have one of these two expressions but not both:
$$ u^2 + 27 v^2 = p, $$
$$ 4 u^2 + 2 uv + 7 v^2 = p.  $$
The (form) class group of discriminant $-108$ is
$$ \langle 1,0,27 \rangle, \; \; \langle 4,2,7 \rangle, \; \; \langle 4,-2,7 \rangle.$$
Gauss composition gives explicit formulas from choices taken using the appropriate one of the above.  Why not, made two separate lists, then combined. Easier to see the patterns.

==================================

```
31 = 2^2 + 27 * 1^2 
 x = 308;  y = 30 =  2 3 5 = 1 * 31 - 1 = 5 * 31 - 125
 x = 124;  y = 62 =  2 31



43 = 4^2 + 27 * 1^2 
 x = 520;  y = 42 =  2 3 7 = 1 * 43 - 1 = 6 * 43 - 216
 x = 344;  y = 86 =  2 43


109 = 1^2 + 27 * 2^2 
 x = 646;  y = 420 =  2^2 3 5 7 = 5 * 109 - 125 = 7 * 109 - 343
 x = 218;  y = 436 =  2^2 109


127 = 10^2 + 27 * 1^2 
 x = 2540;  y = 254 =  2 127
 x = 380;  y = 546 =  2 3 7 13 = 6 * 127 - 216 = 7 * 127 - 343


157 = 7^2 + 27 * 2^2 
 x = 3850;  y = 156 =  2^2 3 13 = 1 * 157 - 1 = 12 * 157 - 1728
 x = 2198;  y = 628 =  2^2 157


223 = 14^2 + 27 * 1^2 
 x = 6244;  y = 446 =  2 223
 x = 3220;  y = 1122 =  2 3 11 17 = 6 * 223 - 216 = 11 * 223 - 1331


229 = 11^2 + 27 * 2^2 
 x = 5038;  y = 916 =  2^2 229
 x = 4466;  y = 1020 =  2^2 3 5 17 = 5 * 229 - 125 = 12 * 229 - 1728


277 = 13^2 + 27 * 2^2 
 x = 7202;  y = 1108 =  2^2 277
 x = 4030;  y = 1596 =  2^2 3 7 19 = 7 * 277 - 343 = 12 * 277 - 1728


283 = 16^2 + 27 * 1^2 
 x = 9056;  y = 566 =  2 283
 x = 5600;  y = 1482 =  2 3 13 19 = 6 * 283 - 216 = 13 * 283 - 2197
```

====================================

```
7 =  4 * 0^2 + 2 * 0 * 1  + 7 *  1^2 
 x = 20;  y = 6 =  2 3 = 1 * 7 - 1 = 2 * 7 - 8
 x = 7;  y = 7 =  7


13 =  4 * 1^2 + 2 * 1 * 1  + 7 *  1^2 
 x = 70;  y = 12 =  2^2 3 = 1 * 13 - 1 = 3 * 13 - 27
 x = 65;  y = 13 =  13


19 =  4 * 2^2 + 2 * 2 * -1  + 7 *  -1^2 
 x = 133;  y = 19 =  19
 x = 56;  y = 30 =  2 3 5 = 2 * 19 - 8 = 3 * 19 - 27


37 =  4 * 3^2 + 2 * 3 * -1  + 7 *  -1^2 
 x = 407;  y = 37 =  37
 x = 110;  y = 84 =  2^2 3 7 = 3 * 37 - 27 = 4 * 37 - 64


61 =  4 * 1^2 + 2 * 1 * -3  + 7 *  -3^2 
 x = 182;  y = 180 =  2^2 3^2 5 = 4 * 61 - 64 = 5 * 61 - 125
 x = 61;  y = 183 =  3 61


67 =  4 * 2^2 + 2 * 2 * -3  + 7 *  -3^2 
 x = 880;  y = 126 =  2 3^2 7 = 2 * 67 - 8 = 7 * 67 - 343
 x = 335;  y = 201 =  3 67


73 =  4 * 1^2 + 2 * 1 * 3  + 7 *  3^2 
 x = 1190;  y = 72 =  2^3 3^2 = 1 * 73 - 1 = 8 * 73 - 512
 x = 511;  y = 219 =  3 73


79 =  4 * 4^2 + 2 * 4 * 1  + 7 *  1^2 
 x = 1343;  y = 79 =  79
 x = 884;  y = 210 =  2 3 5 7 = 3 * 79 - 27 = 7 * 79 - 343


97 =  4 * 5^2 + 2 * 5 * -1  + 7 *  -1^2 
 x = 1843;  y = 97 =  97
 x = 1330;  y = 264 =  2^3 3 11 = 3 * 97 - 27 = 8 * 97 - 512


103 =  4 * 4^2 + 2 * 4 * -3  + 7 *  -3^2 
 x = 1820;  y = 198 =  2 3^2 11 = 2 * 103 - 8 = 9 * 103 - 729
 x = 1339;  y = 309 =  3 103


139 =  4 * 6^2 + 2 * 6 * -1  + 7 *  -1^2 
 x = 3197;  y = 139 =  139
 x = 2576;  y = 390 =  2 3 5 13 = 3 * 139 - 27 = 10 * 139 - 1000


151 =  4 * 4^2 + 2 * 4 * 3  + 7 *  3^2 
 x = 2869;  y = 453 =  3 151
 x = 1748;  y = 630 =  2 3^2 5 7 = 5 * 151 - 125 = 9 * 151 - 729


163 =  4 * 6^2 + 2 * 6 * 1  + 7 *  1^2 
 x = 4075;  y = 163 =  163
 x = 3400;  y = 462 =  2 3 7 11 = 3 * 163 - 27 = 11 * 163 - 1331



181 =  4 * 3^2 + 2 * 3 * -5  + 7 *  -5^2 
 x = 3458;  y = 660 =  2^2 3 5 11 = 4 * 181 - 64 = 11 * 181 - 1331
 x = 1267;  y = 905 =  5 181


193 =  4 * 5^2 + 2 * 5 * 3  + 7 *  3^2 
 x = 4439;  y = 579 =  3 193
 x = 1150;  y = 1008 =  2^4 3^2 7 = 7 * 193 - 343 = 9 * 193 - 729


199 =  4 * 4^2 + 2 * 4 * -5  + 7 *  -5^2 
 x = 5236;  y = 390 =  2 3 5 13 = 2 * 199 - 8 = 13 * 199 - 2197
 x = 2189;  y = 995 =  5 199


211 =  4 * 2^2 + 2 * 2 * 5  + 7 *  5^2 
 x = 6032;  y = 210 =  2 3 5 7 = 1 * 211 - 1 = 14 * 211 - 2744
 x = 2743;  y = 1055 =  5 211



241 =  4 * 3^2 + 2 * 3 * 5  + 7 *  5^2 
 x = 7378;  y = 240 =  2^4 3 5 = 1 * 241 - 1 = 15 * 241 - 3375
 x = 4097;  y = 1205 =  5 241


271 =  4 * 8^2 + 2 * 8 * -3  + 7 *  -3^2 
 x = 7859;  y = 813 =  3 271
 x = 812;  y = 1710 =  2 3^2 5 19 = 9 * 271 - 729 = 10 * 271 - 1000
```

==========================================

```
7 =  4 * 0^2 + 2 * 0 * 1  + 7 *  1^2 
 x = 20;  y = 6 =  2 3 = 1 * 7 - 1 = 2 * 7 - 8
 x = 7;  y = 7 =  7


13 =  4 * 1^2 + 2 * 1 * 1  + 7 *  1^2 
 x = 70;  y = 12 =  2^2 3 = 1 * 13 - 1 = 3 * 13 - 27
 x = 65;  y = 13 =  13


19 =  4 * 2^2 + 2 * 2 * -1  + 7 *  -1^2 
 x = 133;  y = 19 =  19
 x = 56;  y = 30 =  2 3 5 = 2 * 19 - 8 = 3 * 19 - 27


31 = 2^2 + 27 * 1^2 
 x = 308;  y = 30 =  2 3 5 = 1 * 31 - 1 = 5 * 31 - 125
 x = 124;  y = 62 =  2 31


37 =  4 * 3^2 + 2 * 3 * -1  + 7 *  -1^2 
 x = 407;  y = 37 =  37
 x = 110;  y = 84 =  2^2 3 7 = 3 * 37 - 27 = 4 * 37 - 64


43 = 4^2 + 27 * 1^2 
 x = 520;  y = 42 =  2 3 7 = 1 * 43 - 1 = 6 * 43 - 216
 x = 344;  y = 86 =  2 43


61 =  4 * 1^2 + 2 * 1 * -3  + 7 *  -3^2 
 x = 182;  y = 180 =  2^2 3^2 5 = 4 * 61 - 64 = 5 * 61 - 125
 x = 61;  y = 183 =  3 61


67 =  4 * 2^2 + 2 * 2 * -3  + 7 *  -3^2 
 x = 880;  y = 126 =  2 3^2 7 = 2 * 67 - 8 = 7 * 67 - 343
 x = 335;  y = 201 =  3 67


73 =  4 * 1^2 + 2 * 1 * 3  + 7 *  3^2 
 x = 1190;  y = 72 =  2^3 3^2 = 1 * 73 - 1 = 8 * 73 - 512
 x = 511;  y = 219 =  3 73


79 =  4 * 4^2 + 2 * 4 * 1  + 7 *  1^2 
 x = 1343;  y = 79 =  79
 x = 884;  y = 210 =  2 3 5 7 = 3 * 79 - 27 = 7 * 79 - 343


97 =  4 * 5^2 + 2 * 5 * -1  + 7 *  -1^2 
 x = 1843;  y = 97 =  97
 x = 1330;  y = 264 =  2^3 3 11 = 3 * 97 - 27 = 8 * 97 - 512


103 =  4 * 4^2 + 2 * 4 * -3  + 7 *  -3^2 
 x = 1820;  y = 198 =  2 3^2 11 = 2 * 103 - 8 = 9 * 103 - 729
 x = 1339;  y = 309 =  3 103


109 = 1^2 + 27 * 2^2 
 x = 646;  y = 420 =  2^2 3 5 7 = 5 * 109 - 125 = 7 * 109 - 343
 x = 218;  y = 436 =  2^2 109


127 = 10^2 + 27 * 1^2 
 x = 2540;  y = 254 =  2 127
 x = 380;  y = 546 =  2 3 7 13 = 6 * 127 - 216 = 7 * 127 - 343


139 =  4 * 6^2 + 2 * 6 * -1  + 7 *  -1^2 
 x = 3197;  y = 139 =  139
 x = 2576;  y = 390 =  2 3 5 13 = 3 * 139 - 27 = 10 * 139 - 1000


151 =  4 * 4^2 + 2 * 4 * 3  + 7 *  3^2 
 x = 2869;  y = 453 =  3 151
 x = 1748;  y = 630 =  2 3^2 5 7 = 5 * 151 - 125 = 9 * 151 - 729


157 = 7^2 + 27 * 2^2 
 x = 3850;  y = 156 =  2^2 3 13 = 1 * 157 - 1 = 12 * 157 - 1728
 x = 2198;  y = 628 =  2^2 157


163 =  4 * 6^2 + 2 * 6 * 1  + 7 *  1^2 
 x = 4075;  y = 163 =  163
 x = 3400;  y = 462 =  2 3 7 11 = 3 * 163 - 27 = 11 * 163 - 1331


181 =  4 * 3^2 + 2 * 3 * -5  + 7 *  -5^2 
 x = 3458;  y = 660 =  2^2 3 5 11 = 4 * 181 - 64 = 11 * 181 - 1331
 x = 1267;  y = 905 =  5 181


193 =  4 * 5^2 + 2 * 5 * 3  + 7 *  3^2 
 x = 4439;  y = 579 =  3 193
 x = 1150;  y = 1008 =  2^4 3^2 7 = 7 * 193 - 343 = 9 * 193 - 729


199 =  4 * 4^2 + 2 * 4 * -5  + 7 *  -5^2 
 x = 5236;  y = 390 =  2 3 5 13 = 2 * 199 - 8 = 13 * 199 - 2197
 x = 2189;  y = 995 =  5 199


211 =  4 * 2^2 + 2 * 2 * 5  + 7 *  5^2 
 x = 6032;  y = 210 =  2 3 5 7 = 1 * 211 - 1 = 14 * 211 - 2744
 x = 2743;  y = 1055 =  5 211


223 = 14^2 + 27 * 1^2 
 x = 6244;  y = 446 =  2 223
 x = 3220;  y = 1122 =  2 3 11 17 = 6 * 223 - 216 = 11 * 223 - 1331


229 = 11^2 + 27 * 2^2 
 x = 5038;  y = 916 =  2^2 229
 x = 4466;  y = 1020 =  2^2 3 5 17 = 5 * 229 - 125 = 12 * 229 - 1728


241 =  4 * 3^2 + 2 * 3 * 5  + 7 *  5^2 
 x = 7378;  y = 240 =  2^4 3 5 = 1 * 241 - 1 = 15 * 241 - 3375
 x = 4097;  y = 1205 =  5 241


271 =  4 * 8^2 + 2 * 8 * -3  + 7 *  -3^2 
 x = 7859;  y = 813 =  3 271
 x = 812;  y = 1710 =  2 3^2 5 19 = 9 * 271 - 729 = 10 * 271 - 1000


277 = 13^2 + 27 * 2^2 
 x = 7202;  y = 1108 =  2^2 277
 x = 4030;  y = 1596 =  2^2 3 7 19 = 7 * 277 - 343 = 12 * 277 - 1728


283 = 16^2 + 27 * 1^2 
 x = 9056;  y = 566 =  2 283
 x = 5600;  y = 1482 =  2 3 13 19 = 6 * 283 - 216 = 13 * 283 - 2197
```

==========================================

Comment: In fact, I only considered irreducible  cubics in which case I believe this is true (in which case I will edit my post - or correct it?). Your analysis is more general if I understand correcly but I know nothing about class group or Gauss composition